How to obtain the first law of BH mechanics from the Smarr formula
In general relativity coupled to electromagnetism in $d$ dimensions, the Smarr formula relates the thermodynamical variables present in a rotating, electrically charged black hole. More specifically, it may be expressed as
\begin{equation}
M=\frac{d-2}{d-3} \left(TS+\Omega_\mathcal{H}^n J_n\right)+\left(\Phi_\mathcal{H}-\Phi_\infty\right)Q
\end{equation}
where $M$ denotes the mass of the black hole spacetime, $T$ its temperature, $S$ the entropy, $\Omega_\mathcal{H}^n$ and $J_n$ the angular velocities and momenta respectively, $\Phi_{\mathcal{H},\infty}$ the electrostatic potential at the horizon and infinity respectively and $Q$ the electric charge.
The first law of BH mechanics relates the variation of the thermodynamical variables with each other. In the same setting, it reads:
\begin{equation}
\delta M=T\delta S+\Omega_\mathcal{H}^n\delta J_n +(\Phi_\mathcal{H}-\Phi_\infty)\delta Q
\end{equation}
It is often stated that the Smarr formula is the "integrated" version of the first law, but both of them are usually obtained via different methods.
$\textbf{My question}$
I was wondering how one could directly obtain the first law from the Smarr formula by performing directly a variation of the Smarr formula. Using the chain rule, one encounters terms like $\delta \Omega_\mathcal{H}^n J_n$ and $\delta T S$, and I do not know of any way of expressing $\delta T$ as a linear combination of $\delta M, \delta J, \delta  Q$ and $\delta S$.
I can obtain expressions like $T=\frac{\partial M}{\partial S}$, but I do not see how this helps.
One way of solving this issue is if I was able to compute $\frac{\partial T}{\partial M}, \frac{\partial T}{\partial J}$ and so on, since therefore, $\delta T=\frac{\partial T}{\partial M}\delta M +\frac{\partial T}{\partial J}\delta J+\dots$
Furthermore, I cannot use Euler's homogeneity theorem to obtain the previous derivatives, as the temperature, angular velocity etc. are not extensive quantities.
I guess this question may be rephrased in purely thermodynamical terms, maybe as how to obtain the variation of the chemical potentials associated to the charges in terms of the variation of the charges.

Your question is exactly how the first law was originally derived in Bardeen, Carter and Hawking's "The four laws of black hole mechanics" back in 1973, if you can obtain the paper. The gist is that one cannot do it purely by thermodynamical arguments. You must consider two Kerr solutions and a linear perturbation carrying from one solution to the other. Essentially you must evaluate the variation in area, and by choosing vectors wisely you can evaluate terms like $\delta\Omega J$ and $\delta T S$ and substitute in the variation of the Smarr formula to get the first law.

Thanks for your comment. Is there an obvious reason why one cannot obtain those results in purely thermodynamical terms? The first law seems to be quite general, even for horizons not coming from black holes.

I don't think there is any obvious reason, it might be that nobody could do it just yet. But I think that the first law seems more restrictive than you suggest. Wald's "Black hole entropy is Noether charge" and Hawking, Horowitz and Ross' "Entropy, area and black hole pairs" argue for extreme black holes having zero entropy despite having non-zero area. Both say that the issue is that entropy comes not only from having event horizons but that it is crucial to have a Killing horizon. Maybe thermodynamics can't account for this question directly, I don't know
